# QStringList QCoreApplication::arguments() - in what situation is index 0 not the application path in Windows?

Tags: windows, qt

The documentation for `QStringList QCoreApplication::arguments()` (Qt) states that:

> ***Usually*** arguments().at(0) is the
>   program name, arguments().at(1) is the
>   first argument, and arguments().last()
>   is the last argument. ***See the note
>   below about Windows.***

It further elaborates:

> On Windows, [...] the arguments() are
>   constructed from the return value of
>   GetCommandLine(). As a result of this,
>   ***the string given by arguments().at(0)
>   might not be the program name on
>   Windows, depending on how the
>   application was started.***

Referring to the last bold part, I am curious about which situation does this applies in. The Qt documentation doesn't explain it nor does [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156%28VS.85%29.aspx)'s (WINAPI) documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen when your program is spawned via [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) - have a look at the description for the *lpCommandLine* parameter. Basically it is up to the program calling CreateProcess to fill in that first parameter, so it can happen that the value isn't filled in the usual way.

From the link:

"If both lpApplicationName and lpCommandLine are non-NULL, the null-terminated string pointed to by lpApplicationName specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by lpCommandLine specifies the command line. The new process can use GetCommandLine to retrieve the entire command line. Console processes written in C can use the argc and argv arguments to parse the command line. Because argv[0] is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line."

Similarly, this can happen if your program is started from another using the [spawn](http://www.warpspeed.com.au/cgi-bin/inf2html.cmd?..%5Chtml%5Cbook%5CToolkt40%5CXPG4REF.INF+244) family of functions. There, the documentation states:

"At least one argument, either arg0 or argv[0], must be passed to the child process. By convention, this argument is a copy of the pathname argument. However, a different value will not produce an error."